# Kivy - threads, queues, clocks and Python sockets

Tags: kivy

I'm brand new to Kivy, and also new to GUI, but not new to programming.

I am completely missing the boat, the canoe, and the airplane on using Kivy.

In 30 years of programming, from machine code, assembly, Fortran, C, C++, Java, Python, I've never tried to use a language such as Kivy who's documentation is this thin, because it's so new.  I know it'll get better, but I'm trying to use it now.

In my code, I'm trying to implement Queueing, so that I can obtain Python socket data.  In normal Python programming, I would have IPC via a Queue - put data in, get data out.

I understand from Kivy, mostly from what I've read in various forums, but can't say I've found it in the documentation at kivy.org,  that I can't do the following:

- Kivy needs to be in it's own thread.
- Nothing in Kivy should sleep.
- Nothing in Kivy should do blocking IO.

After a LOT of Google searching, the only thing I've actually found that approaches being useful, is an [informative note here on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031262/altering-a-kivy-property-from-another-thread) .  However, while it almost solves my problem, the answer assumes I know more about Kivy than I do; I don't know how to incorporate the answer.

If someone could take the time to put together a COMPLETE short demo of using that example, or one of your own unique COMPLETE answers, I would much appreciate it!

Here's some short code I put together, but it doesn't work, because it blocks on the get() call.

```
from Queue import Queue
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from threading import Thread

class ClockedQueue(BoxLayout):
    text1 = StringProperty("Start")

    def __init__(self):
        super(ClockedQueue,self).__init__()
        self.q = Queue()
        self.i=0
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.get, 2)

    def get(self,dt):
        print("get entry")

        val = self.q.get()
        print(self.i + val)
        self.i += 1

class ClockedQueueApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ClockedQueue()

class SourceQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        q = Queue()
        for word in ['First','Second']:
            q.put(word)
        print("SourceQueue finished.")

def main():

    th = Thread(target=SourceQueue)
    th.start()

    ClockedQueueApp().run()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':


    main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're not having a problem with Kivy here, you're having a problem with everything else in your code. `SourceQueue` does nothing, as it only creates a temporary local variable. It's also never referenced by anything else in your code. It doesn't need to be in a thread, and it definitely shouldn't be the `target` of a thread. As for `get` blocking, that's as simple as using `get_nowait` and catching `Queue.Empty`.

Answer (score 4):

> Here's some short code I put together, but it doesn't work, because it blocks on the get() call.

So what you really want to do is get items from your queue in a non-blocking way?

There are multiple ways to do this. The simplest seems to be to just check if the queue has any items before getting one - `Queue` has several methods that help with this, including checking if it is empty or setting whether `get` is allowed to be blocking (by setting its first argument to `False`). If you just do this instead of calling `get` on its own, you won't block things waiting for the queue to have any items - if it's empty or you can't immediately `get` anything, you just do nothing.

I don't know what you want to do with the items you get from the queue, but if it's short operations that don't take long then you won't need anything more than this. For instance, you could `Clock.schedule_interval` the `get` method to happen every frame, do nothing if the queue is empty, or operate on the data if you get something back. No blocking, and no messing with your own threads.

You *can* also create your own thread and run the blocking code in it, which is general way to deal with blocking issues, especially tasks that can't be split up into short sections that can be performed between frames. I don't know about the details of this, but it should just involve using python threads normally. You can check the source of kivy's `UrlRequest` for an example, this can download a web source in a background thread.

Edit: Also your SourceQueue is messed up (you override its `__init__` to make a new queue that you don't store anywhere), and your clock scheduling has a meaningless third argument `false` which isn't even defined. I don't know what's going on here, it probably affects what you're trying to do, but doesn't matter to my general answer above.

Comment: Thanks inclement, but like I said, I'm looking for an example of how to do this or implement the stackoverflow link I posted.  But thanks for your consideration in answering.  Thanks for the catch on the 'false'; I'll try to edit that out.

Comment: What I ultimately would like to do is: 1) have a thread that's running that can interface with a socket.  I've already got a lot of code in that arena that needs to be running.  2) that running thread gets data from the socket, does it's work, then pushes the results onto a Queue that can be read from within Kivy.  3) Kivy reads the input Queue, updates the GUI.  Thanks again for your question.

Comment: What I've said above covers the basic structure of what you need for the kivy part - something like `Clock.schedule_interval` a function that checks the queue and acts on it if it has any entries. I don't know much about threads though, so I'm afraid I can't help there. It should be independent of kivy itself, so you can directly pursue the question of how to run code in a thread - in this case, reading from a socket and pushing to your queue.

Comment: inclement, thanks for your comments.  I'm looking for an example.

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to create something that worked.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Here's the code (because I'm new, Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post it as answering my own question until 5:00 AM)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  threads_and_kivy.py
#  
'''threads_and_kivy.py
Trying to build up a foundation that satisfies the following:
    - has a thread that will implement code that:
        - simulates reads data from a Python socket
        - works on the data
        - puts the data onto a Python Queue
    - has a Kivy mainthread that:
        - via class ShowGUI
            - reads data from the Queue
            - updates a class variable of type StringProperty so it will
                update the label_text property.

'''

from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty
import time


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


kv='''

<ShowGUI>:
    Label:
        text: str(root.label_text)
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)

q = Queue()    


class SimSocket():
    global q

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.q = queue

    def put_on_queue(self):
        print("<-----..threaded..SimSocket.put_on_queue(): entry")
        for i in range(10):
            print(".....threaded.....SimSocket.put_on_queue(): Loop " + str(i))
            time.sleep(1)#just here to sim occassional data send
            self.some_data = ["SimSocket.put_on_queue(): Data Loop " + str(i)]
            self.q.put(self.some_data)
        print("..threaded..SimSocket.put_on_queue(): thread ends")

class ShowGUI(BoxLayout):
    label_text = StringProperty("Initial - not data")
    global q

    def __init__(self):
        super(ShowGUI, self).__init__()
        print("ShowGUI.__init__() entry")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.get_from_queue, 1.0)

    def get_from_queue(self, dt):
        print("---------> ShowGUI.get_from_queue() entry")
        try:
            queue_data = q.get(timeout = 5)
            self.label_text = queue_data[0]
            for qd in queue_data:
                print("SimKivy.get_from_queue(): got data from queue: " + qd)
        except Empty:
            print("Error - no data received on queue.")
            print("Unschedule Clock's schedule")
            Clock.unschedule(self.get_from_queue)


class KivyGui(App):
    def build(self):
        return ShowGUI()



def main():

    global q
    ss = SimSocket(q)

    simSocket_thread = Thread(name="simSocket",target=ss.put_on_queue)
    simSocket_thread.start()

    print("Starting KivyGui().run()")

    KivyGui().run()


    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: in addition , you can take a look to http://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html#using-twisted-inside-kivy for integrating twisted . It will permit you to do async call