# Run Kivy Application method in background

Tags: python, kivy

I have built a desktop [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) application with some methods that perform changes in my app as well as other calculations that take some time (around 30 seconds). When I call these methods, the app freezes during their execution, which is not desirable. Is there a way to prevent the app from freezing and instead display some kind of popup with an animated gif, so that the user knows the app is processing something and did not crash/stop responding?

I have tried to use multiprocessing to run these methods in the background while an informative Popup appears, but these processes do not share memory and data structures with the main app process. So, even though the method run successfully and the popup was shown, there were no changes in the app...

Anyway, this is the multiprocessing code:

```
def run_in_background(self, func, *args):

    def run_func(m, a):
        # Execute the function with args
        m(*a)

    def check_process(proc, dt):
        if not proc.is_alive():
            Clock.unschedule(check_func)
            self.dismiss_popup()

    # Create background process and start it
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_func, args=(func, args))
    p.start()

    # Create waiting dialog
    content = CrunchData()
    # Show waiting popup
    self.show_popup(title="Some title", content=content, size=(400, 300))

    # Create schedulled check for process state
    check_func = partial(check_process, p)
    Clock.schedule_interval(check_func, .1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use subprocess, Python have a bad reputation with its GIL for the thread management, https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @e-nouri, subprocess would be a bad fit here.  multiprocess gets around the GIL anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a good start to your problem, but polling is_alive is not what you want to do.  Since you are only doing one background task and showing a dialog, you *could* use either threading OR multiprocessing for this.  Their API is very similar.

To avoid polling, you can use a [processing pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) (easier to deal with) and pass a callback to `pool.apply_async`.

This callback will not be run on the main thread, though, so if you need to run code on the main thread you will need to schedule it in your callback.

An alternative is just to use a separate thread instead of process, and use Kivy's clock to schedule a function call at the end of the thread function.  See [kivy threading docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#threading).

This SO answer is also an option for transferring data from a thread to the main thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22033066.  It's from a Kivy dev.

Comment: So, using pool.apply_async causes a series of errors due to unpickable objects. This is because the functions I'm passing are class methods and not top level functions? Using Kivy's clocks and threading, still causes the app to freeze in long loops. I've adapted my code with [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application) example, but the freezing remains.

Comment: yes, to use multiprocessing anything sent from one process to another must be pickleable.  You can use class methods if the class object can be pickled, but I don't think kivy objects can.  You can either separate the long-running function into it's own function/object, or stick to threads.  I am not really sure what you are seeing with threads since there's no example code to try.

Comment: Using threads, if I put the `@mainthread` decorator on the target function, it freezes the app everything is [normal](http://i60.tinypic.com/xppu3b.png). When I remove the `@mainthread` decorator, the app doesn't freeze but I get [this](http://s11.postimg.org/mtgr6348z/with_threads.png)

Comment: ```@mainthread``` will run the whole function on the main (GUI) thread.  The function that is taking a long time should be run in a background thread.  Then at the end of that function, when it is done working, you call a second function.  This second function can have the ```@mainthread``` decorator or be scheduled with ```Clock```.