# Kivy - multiprocessing. call kivy widget functions via other processes / Alter Kivy Listproperty from outside kivy's thread

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy, clock, listproperty

Following Matt's answer from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031262/altering-a-kivy-property-from-another-thread) I am trying to use 
`clock.schedule` in another process in order to alter my `ListProperty` called "data_items" but still I get the error *"global name 'set_property' is not defined"*.

beedo.py:

```
class MyW(Widget):
data_items = ListProperty([])
def set_property(camera, *largs):
    self.data_items.append(camera)
    print(data_items)
    return
....   

class beedoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyW()
    ....

def do_list(camera):
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(set_property, camera))
    print "do list startet.."

def socket_server()
    ....

def event_handler
    ....
    list1 = Process (target=do_list, args=(camera))
    list1.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server1 = Process (target=socket_server, args=(....)
    server2 = Process (target=socket_server, args=(....)
    handler = Process (target=event_handler, args=(....)

    server1.start()
    server2.start()
    handler.start()

    beedoApp().run()

    server1.join()
    server2.join()
    handler.join()
```

In the file beedo.kv I defined a `SimpleListAdapter`:

```
ListView:
     adapter:
     sla.SimpleListAdapter(data=root.data_items, cls=ListItemButton)
```

The screen of the alarm device looks like this:

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqQzD.png)

I have uploaded the complete code here:

`beedo.py`
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyqpfefkia6lj0r/beedo.py?dl=0

Please, if you can help I would be really thankful !!  regards, Pipe007

Comment: That answer is about using threads (in which case there's a shared global context including the set_property function), whereas you are using processes (in which case there isn't). I guess you need to do some inter-process communication if this is the way you want to go, e.g. with simple Kivy apps we often use osc (available as kivy.libs.osc).

Comment: Hi inclement! Thank your for your tips! Could you please give me some more hints on how to realise this communication with kivy.libs.osc? Thank you! PS: I tried to use a namespace and the multiprocess.manager, but could not get it to work..

Comment: I think I found a link with an explenation of this osc network stuff [link](https://kivy.org/planet/2014/01/building-a-background-application-on-android-with-kivy/). I will rather try to manage with threading I think..